# What id to put in fragmentTransaction.replace() method argument?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to call fragment from fragment.

I am using following code:

```
Fragment fragment = new TeamDetails3();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

My current fragment layout is `team_details3.xml` and the fragment which i am calling has layout `team_details4.xml`. I also tried putting

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.team_details4, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.team_details3, fragment);
```

but they show error

I am getting these errors if i put `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)`-

```
No view found for id 0x7f080159 (com.pepup.league:id/frame_container) for fragment TeamDetails3{41916708 #1 id=0x7f080159}
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 12:07:49.420      347-363/? E/AppErrorDialog﹕ Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin activity posted

Comment: So you are only trying to replace the fragment?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yeah..i called fragment from activity nd thats working fine but when i try to replace tht fragment with another fragment it shows error

Comment: then use this as the id `android.R.id.content
`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thanks a lott!!can u post this as answer so that i can select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use one layout id for changing fragment as the layout in fragment managers

You can use this id `android.R.id.content` as the main layout for changing the fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I guess it should work

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentB, tag);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    ft.commit();
```

Comment: what to put in tag-"getTag()"?

Comment: @Stranger fragment.getTag(); use this

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Hope it helps

```
            //calling the next fragment. i have written it in another class which extends Fragment
            //ContactsFragment is the fragment that I am calling
            ContactsFragment mContactsFragment = new ContactsFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
            //here default layout is a linear layout in the xml file of this activity  
            transaction.replace(R.id.defaultLayout,new ContactsFragment());
            transaction.commit();
```

Basically in `transaction.replace()` the first parameter will be the id of the layout in which you want to place your fragment. And the second parameter should be the fragment.

Comment: if i put the id of  xml file layout of this fragment or activity it shows in red cannot resolve symbol..

Comment: also it cannot resolve symbol R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left

Comment: @Stranger remove the R.anim.enter_fromright I have written a file for that it wont work in your code. Try cleaning your project and building it again

Comment: okay..so transaction.replace() contans id of layout of current fragment or activity?

Comment: my current fragment xml layout is team_details2.xml i tried putting R.id.team_details2 and R.layout.team_details2 but both shows error..first one shows compiling error and second one while running

Comment: can u post your xml file i can give u a better solution in that way

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 FragmentTransaction    fragmentTransition = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        TeamDetails3 fragmentClass = new TeamDetails3 ();
                        fragmentTransition.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, fragmentClass ,"");
                        fragmentTransition.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        fragmentTransition.addToBackStack(fragmentClass .getClass().getName());
                        fragmentTransition.commit();
```

Comment: replace it with your framelayout id

Comment: should i replace it with current fragment layout id or activity layout id

Comment: replace with activity layout

Comment: shows same error for-  fragmentTransition.replace(R.layout.team_details, fragmentClass ,"");      Error-No view found for id 0x7f030052 (com.pepup.league:layout/team_details) for fragment TeamDetails3{4194d020 #1 id=0x7f030052 }

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the developers site. [FragmentTransaction.replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment))

Like it mentions, the id needs to be the id of the container where you need to place this fragment. Since you began with `android.R.id.content`, I'm guessing that is what you need to 
pass, unless there is other code that isn't included in the question.